# Is it possible train a Convolution neural network in python and convert the trained network into c code?

Tags: python, matlab, conv-neural-network

I am wondering if an already trained convolutional neural network can be represented as a formula just like a perceptron can (x1w1 + x2w2 + ... = PREDICTION). I know that the formula could be a lot more complicated like this, but in general would it be possible to train a CNN in Python or Matlab, get the weights and create an arithmetic, exponential, whatever formula made with those acquired weights?

I want to do this because I am trying classify in a PIC32 which I think does not have the capacity to perform a CNN within itself.

Or do you know if there is a "c library" that can do CNNs?

Comment: Even if there isn't a full CNN implementation that would fit on your chip, you could probably just place the compute-intensive operations (i.e.: the matrix multiplications) on your chip. Do you have easy/fast communication between the chip and a normal computer?

Comment: It's definitely possible. You're going to have to do the computations in parallel though for each convolutional filter. You might run into memory issues, depending on the size of the network. I haven't tried this myself without an optimised machine/deep learning library